# Show tree view inside a form view with one field in common between models. In Odoo 9

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-9

We have the model "**website.support.ticket**", with the "**partner_id**" field.
We have the model "**crm.lead**", with the "**partner_id**" field.
(Two models with one field in common)

The idea is to put a page (dropdown) to the view of **crm_lead** to see the list of all **website_support_tickets** related with the **partner** of the **crm_lead** current view.

In the xml file we have this code, working fine:

```xml
<record id="view_order_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Opportunities Extend</field>
    <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_oppor"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <page name="lead" position="after">
        <page string="Support Tickets">
          <field name="support_ticket_lines"/>
        </page>
      </page>
    </field>  
</record>
```

In the python file I have tried to connect the models with a related field:

```py
class crm_lead_extend(models.Model):
    _inherit = ['crm.lead']

    support_ticket_lines = fields.One2many(related='partner_id.support_ticket_ids')
```

But it shows an error:

in _setup_related_full
       field = target._fields[name]
    KeyError: 'support_ticket_ids'

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got that error because you are expecting that the field `support_ticket_ids` exists in the `res.partner` model, however, you have not declared it there.

Preserve your code, and add to `res.partner` model the following:

```
class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    support_ticket_ids = fields.One2many(
        comodel_name='website.support.ticket',
        inverse_name='partner_id',
        string='Support Ticket Lines',
    )
```

Comment: When I install the custom module for the first time it works everything ok but if I update the module, it show the same error again. Why?

Comment: Have you put the code I wrote you in a file included in the `__manifest__.py`? If so, please, can you paste your code extended? As I can see in the section you wrote here, you must have a field named `partner_id` in `crm.lead` model. That field is a Many2one pointing to `res.partner` model, I guess. If this fact is true, you want to fill in the field named `support_ticket_lines` (model `crm.lead`) with the content of the field named `support_ticket_ids` (model `res.partner`), don't you?

Comment: Yes, everything is working fine with your code at the installation of the module, but I cannot update the module anymore. I don't know why. But this is another problem.

Comment: It was needed to put 'website_support' as dependence of my custom_module in order to update the module without errors. It is related with the priority of the module load